# Recursive python code same logic leads to different outputs. Why is it so?

Tags: python, list, recursion, data-structures, permutation

```
def perm(res, visited, subset, nums):
    if len(subset) == len(nums):
        res.append(subset)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if i not in visited:
            visited.add(i)
            perm(res, visited, **subset+[nums[i]]**, nums)
            visited.remove(i)   
def permute(nums):
    visited = set()
    res = []
    subset = []
    perm(res,visited,subset,nums)
    return res
    
print(permute([1,2,3]))
```

gives output as expected that is [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
but

```
def perm(res, visited, subset, nums):
    if len(subset) == len(nums):
        res.append(subset)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if i not in visited:
            **subset.append(nums[i])**
            visited.add(i)
            perm(res, visited, subset, nums)
            visited.remove(i)
            **subset.remove(nums[i]) **     
def permute(nums):
    visited = set()
    res = []
    subset = []
    perm(res,visited,subset,nums)
    return res
    
print(permute([1,2,3]))
```

gives output as [[], [], [], [], [], []]

I have tried executing them. But observed the difference in output.

I have highlighted the difference in code. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `.append()`, you are mutating that list in place, and passing down a reference to that same list. When you later call `.remove`, you are taking items off of that list.

On the other hand `+` builds a new list, which does not see (top level) modifications to the old list.

Changing your code to :

```
def perm(res, visited, subset, nums):
    if len(subset) == len(nums):
        res.append(subset)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if i not in visited:
            new_subset = subset + [nums[i]]
            visited.add(i)
            perm(res, visited, new_subset, nums)
            visited.remove(i)
def permute(nums):
    visited = set()
    res = []
    subset = []
    perm(res,visited,subset,nums)
    return res
    
print(permute([1,2,3]))
```

yields the expected output.

In general, though, it is a better pattern to return the value a function is calculating, than to pass it a parameter to modify with that result. The latter will give you a lot of headaches.